# Inherited class function results in 'Incompatible types'

Tags: delphi, inheritance, delphi-xe5

We have a software project (Delphi XE5) that runs perfectly fine. It basically displays a diagram with various elements. Now in order to expand it, we have to reimplement the drawing methods, which also works fine. However, we then run into incompatible type problems for other functions in the inherited class.

Unit that describes the diagram elements:

```
unit Elements;

type
TElementA = class
  procedure DrawSomething; virtual;
end;

TElementB = class
  FElementA: TElementA;
  procedure DrawSomething; virtual;
  function ReturnSomething: TElementA;
end;
```

The second unit uses the first one and reimplements basically the drawing procedures:

```
unit ElementsDiff;

uses Elements;

type
TElementA = class(Elements.TElementA)
  procedure DrawSomething; override;
end;

TElementB = class(Elements.TElementB)
  procedure DrawSomething; override;
end;
```

The procedure that uses those classes looks the following:

```
unit Main;

uses
  Elements,
  ElementsDiff;

implementation

procedure MainProcedure;
var
  FElementA: TElementA;
  FElementB: TElementB;
begin
  FElementA := TElementA.Create;
  FElementB := TElementB.Create;
  // do some stuff...
  // ................

  FElementA := FElementB.ReturnSomething;
end;
```

When compiling, of course it doesn't compile cause of the last line. We get a nice error:

```
Incompatible types: 'ElementsDiff.TElementA' and 'Elements.TElementA'
```

meaning: ReturnSomething returns type 'Elements.TElementA', but FElementA is of type 'ElementsDiff.TElementA'. 
I understand the cause of the problem (it's been answered numerous times here already), and the simplest solution would be to just do a typecast, i.e.

```
FElementA := TElementA(FElementB.ReturnSomething);
```

But since it's a rather big software project, much much more complex than the code above, I wonder if there's actually a *better* solution than to just *typecast* every time that function is used.

Any thoughts on how to solve this in a nice way are much appreciated.

Comment: Is it your intention that fElementB declared in Main be of type ElementsDiff.tElementB?

Comment: I assume where you say " function ReturnSomething: FElementA;", you mean " function ReturnSomething: tElementA;"

Comment: @user1008646 : Yes of course.. small typo, I corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The last unit that is inluded 'owns' the type name in case of a collision. Since that is the unit `ElementsDiff`, containing the descendant classes, your main code uses those classes.

The problem then, is that ReturnSomething returns an instance the base class, `Elements.TElementA`.

To solve this, you can (amongst others) declare your variables in Main like this:

```
var
  FElementA: Elements.TElementA;
  FElementB: Elements.TElementB;
```

That way, the variables can contain either the base class or the descendant class without problems, as long as you don't use any methods or properties that only exist in the descendants.

But maybe it's better to give the diff classes a different name to avoid confusion. The classes don't have to have the same name. This will work too:

```
// In ElementDiff:
TElementBDiff = class(TElementB)

// In Main:
var
  ElementB: TElementB;
begin
  ElementB := TElementBDiff.Create;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve these nameclashes is by providing a local alias in unit Main.:

```
type
  TElementA = Elements.TElementA;
  TElementB = Elements.TElementB;
```

This way, the compiler knows which TElementA you want to use.

Comment: That probably won't solve the problem. It is perfectly valid that FElementA is of type ElementsDiff.TElementA on purpose. This problem is not a typical nameclashing issue.

Comment: @Uwe, I think the problem is *exactly* a typical name-clashing issue. The code uses the token `TElementA`, expecting to refer to the type defined in the Elements unit, but instead ends up getting the type defined in ElementsDiff. The function returns the type from Elements, so the compiler correctly rejects the code attempting to assign one to the other. If the caller knows the run-time type to be something more specific than the declared type, then the caller can type-cast later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
TElementB = class(Elements.TElementB)
  procedure DrawSomething; override;
  function ReturnSomething: tElementA; reintroduce;
end;
```

Just be careful that when you implement the new ReturnSomething that you always return an object of type ElementsDiff.tElementA.

I would recommend using AS rather than explicit typecasting.

```
FElementA := FElementB.ReturnSomething as tElementA;
```

This will ensure that the object is really of the type you're expecting.